# The bootstrap required error message is not visible outside the browser window

Tags: bootstrap-4, scroll, viewport, input-field, required-field

There is a form with a lot of input fields, so you have to scroll down to the bottom of the page for the save button to work. However, if I do not fill in a required field, it scrolls to the top of the page, where the required field is located, but the message does not appear. Have you ever met someone like this? Could someone help me? Thank you very much for the answers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There’s a workaround here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/33757